# Q: Can I trigger a Jenkins job from a Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins

The setup is as follows:

- Step 1: I am developing on a windows 10 machine
- Step 2: Building artifacts with Maven (using powershell)
- Step 3: Go to (semi-local) Jenkins which is running in a Linux VM on my machine & trigger a Jenkins job that syncs and deploys my artifacts to the application server running on the VM.

**Q:** Is it possible to automate/merge Steps 2 and 3 in this scenario?

(Building and deploying each takes several minutes)

Comment: If you are using Jenkins I assume you are using a version control system which means by each (commit/push) on Jenkins the job will be triggered?

Comment: git. but this is not a remote system, this is my local "testing" setup that is not relying on git at all. I wrote remote because the jenkins is running in a VM

Comment: simplest is to make you jenkins configuration handle the trigger by your version control system...from where does jenkins get the source to be compiled? From your version control I assume?

Comment: Jenkins gets doesn't get the source at all. It is not compiling the artifacts only deploying ... it copies pre-compiled artifacts from the mounted windows drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Create a custom goal which will trigger the Jenkins with an [URL](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/).

But, ideally, I would suggest to build and deploy using Jenkins by fetching the code from the repository when there is a change

Comment: I found the same article and I agree that this is the solution to my particular problem. However when I go to "Build Triggers" in my Jenkins job there is no option for remote triggers. I'll need to figure out why that is missing. If that had been there I might never have asked this question.

Comment: And I agree completely about git but this is not within my power to change.

Comment: pulling the code from the repository is a little "outdated"

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

I suggest you use webhooks (github, gitlab, bitbucket,...)

Steps will be :

1. Install some plugin in your jenkins in order to expose a job as public url.
2. Configure your webhook in git provider adding url created in step 1
3. Push some changes to your code
4. Your git provider detect this event and execute the url created in step 1
5. Your jenkins job is launched. Put your mvn commands and deploy commands in this job. I suggest you use jenkins pipeline job.

Contact me if you need some help.

Post step by step :

https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks

Comment: Thx. I figured out why the jenkins didn't have credentials or allowed me to create any. Since it runs local in a VM there is no security on it and I can just do curl -X post http://localhost:8080/jobs/JOBNAME/build. I'll check out webhooks.